# Retrofit json mapping to singleton class

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to map data received from retrofit service into a singleton class. It seems because `getInstance()` static method is not called when retrofit maps json to my object, INSTANCE variable is not initialised and next time I call `MyClass.getInstance()` I get object with default values and not what I received from retrofit. How do I go about saving data from retrofit into singleton class.

P.S. I need this because I need to use the same object that I received in first fragment's model, in second fragment in ViewPager.

My singleton class:

```
public final MySingletonClass {

    //pirivate final fields;

    private MySingletonClass() {
        //default initialization fields
    }


    public static MySingletonClass getInstance() {
        return MySingletonClassSingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class MySingletonClassSingletonHelper {
        private static final MySingletonClass INSTANCE = new MySingletonClass();
    }

    //getters

}
```

OK, if anyone need to know how I use retrofit:

```
@Override
public Observable<MySingletonClass> loadData(Integer params) {
    return mRetrofitInterface.getMySingletonClass(params).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}


public interface MySingletonClassService {
@POST("some address")
Observable<MySingletonClass> getMySingletonClass(@Path("idd") Integer idd);
}
```

Comment: Do you want your data to persist through multiple runs of your app or through only one run?

Comment: Just single run. Until next request to the same address (refresh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the best option but you could do it:

```
public final MySingletonClass {

    //private final fields;

    private MyRetrofitObject foo; 

    private MySingletonClass() {
        //default initialization fields
    }


    public static MySingletonClass getInstance() {
        return MySingletonClassSingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class MySingletonClassSingletonHelper {
        private static final MySingletonClass INSTANCE = new MySingletonClass();
    }

    //getters

    public void setObject(MyRetrofitObject foo) {
         this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

when you return the object from Retrofit you then set it on your singleton.

```
 INSTANCE.setObject(fooFromRetrofit);
```

This separates object parsing, from in memory storage

Comment: This is what I thought as well but was hoping that Retrofit itself can deal with singleton mappings. I guess this is as good as it gets.

Comment: honestly this is better than what you are thinking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Do you mean having separate objects that represents received data and object that represents object that is used as singleton from that object? I can see that, i might need to modify object that I use as singleton and this will not affect my object for representing received data. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: exactly thats it :100: